# Jenkins fails when running "service start jenkins"

Tags: jenkins

I installed jenkins on Centos 7 using the following:

```
sudo wget -O /etc/yum.repos.d/jenkins.repo http://pkg.jenkins.io/redhat-stable/jenkins.repo
sudo rpm --import http://pkg.jenkins.io/redhat-stable/jenkins.io.key
yum install jenkins
```

as [described on the official documentation](http://pkg.jenkins-ci.org/redhat-stable/)

However when I run:

```
service start jenkins
```

I get the following error message:

```
Starting jenkins (via systemctl):  Job for jenkins.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status jenkins.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
                                                           [FAILED]
```

Running `systemctl status jenkins.service` gives me this:

```
● jenkins.service - LSB: Jenkins Continuous Integration Server
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/rc.d/init.d/jenkins)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Wed 2016-09-21 16:45:28 BST; 3min 59s ago
     Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)
  Process: 2818 ExecStart=/etc/rc.d/init.d/jenkins start (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Sep 21 16:45:28 webstack.local.caplib jenkins[2818]: at com.sun.akuma.JavaVMArguments.of(JavaVMArguments...04)
Sep 21 16:45:28 webstack.local.caplib jenkins[2818]: at com.sun.akuma.JavaVMArguments.current(JavaVMArgu...92)
Sep 21 16:45:28 webstack.local.caplib jenkins[2818]: at com.sun.akuma.Daemon.daemonize(Daemon.java:106)
Sep 21 16:45:28 webstack.local.caplib jenkins[2818]: at com.sun.akuma.Daemon.all(Daemon.java:88)
Sep 21 16:45:28 webstack.local.caplib jenkins[2818]: ... 6 more
Sep 21 16:45:28 webstack.local.caplib systemd[1]: jenkins.service: control process exited, code=exited s...s=1
Sep 21 16:45:28 webstack.local.caplib systemd[1]: Failed to start LSB: Jenkins Continuous Integration Server.
Sep 21 16:45:28 webstack.local.caplib systemd[1]: Unit jenkins.service entered failed state.
Sep 21 16:45:28 webstack.local.caplib systemd[1]: jenkins.service failed.
Sep 21 16:45:28 webstack.local.caplib jenkins[2818]: [FAILED]
Hint: Some lines were ellipsized, use -l to show in full.
```

and running `journalctl -xe` gives me this:

```
Sep 21 16:45:28 webstack.local.caplib jenkins[2818]: at com.sun.akuma.JavaVMArguments.of(JavaVMArguments.java:
Sep 21 16:45:28 webstack.local.caplib jenkins[2818]: at com.sun.akuma.JavaVMArguments.current(JavaVMArguments.
Sep 21 16:45:28 webstack.local.caplib jenkins[2818]: at com.sun.akuma.Daemon.daemonize(Daemon.java:106)
Sep 21 16:45:28 webstack.local.caplib jenkins[2818]: at com.sun.akuma.Daemon.all(Daemon.java:88)
Sep 21 16:45:28 webstack.local.caplib jenkins[2818]: ... 6 more
Sep 21 16:45:28 webstack.local.caplib runuser[2819]: pam_unix(runuser:session): session closed for user jenkin
Sep 21 16:45:28 webstack.local.caplib systemd[1]: jenkins.service: control process exited, code=exited status=
Sep 21 16:45:28 webstack.local.caplib systemd[1]: Failed to start LSB: Jenkins Continuous Integration Server.
-- Subject: Unit jenkins.service has failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
--
-- Unit jenkins.service has failed.
--
-- The result is failed.
Sep 21 16:45:28 webstack.local.caplib systemd[1]: Unit jenkins.service entered failed state.
Sep 21 16:45:28 webstack.local.caplib systemd[1]: jenkins.service failed.
Sep 21 16:45:28 webstack.local.caplib jenkins[2818]: [FAILED]
Sep 21 16:45:28 webstack.local.caplib polkitd[1392]: Unregistered Authentication Agent for unix-process:2813:8
Sep 21 16:45:28 webstack.local.caplib dhclient[1390]: DHCPREQUEST on eno16777984 to 192.168.15.254 port 67 (xi
Sep 21 16:45:28 webstack.local.caplib dhclient[1390]: DHCPACK from 192.168.15.254 (xid=0x2ab6e6bc)
Sep 21 16:45:30 webstack.local.caplib dhclient[1390]: bound to 192.168.15.120 -- renewal in 865 seconds.
Sep 21 16:45:36 webstack.local.caplib systemd[1]: Starting Cleanup of Temporary Directories...
-- Subject: Unit systemd-tmpfiles-clean.service has begun start-up
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
--
-- Unit systemd-tmpfiles-clean.service has begun starting up.
Sep 21 16:45:36 webstack.local.caplib systemd[1]: Started Cleanup of Temporary Directories.
-- Subject: Unit systemd-tmpfiles-clean.service has finished start-up
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
--
-- Unit systemd-tmpfiles-clean.service has finished starting up.
--
-- The start-up result is done.
```

Both of which is really unhelpful. How do I fix this issue?

Comment: You can check for any error messages in `/var/log/jenkins/jenkins.log`.

Comment: I believe no such file existed

Comment: 1. What Java version are you running?   2. Do you have firewalld or iptables enabled? 3. Try first enabling the service, then start.

Comment: make sure to install java as well. If you installing the jenkins on amazon web server: https://medium.com/@itsmattburgess/installing-jenkins-on-amazon-linux-16aaa02c369c

Comment: for CentOS- try performing the two steps described (stackoverflow ans) here(https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38352806/jenkins-not-able-to-access-java-localhost-jenkins807-starting-jenkins-bash) , if still the issue exists then check if you  already something running on the port where jenkins is trying to run(by default port 8080)

Answer (score 65, accepted):

Similar problem on Ubuntu 16.04.

```
Setting up jenkins (2.72) ...
Job for jenkins.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status jenkins.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
invoke-rc.d: initscript jenkins, action "start" failed.
● jenkins.service - LSB: Start Jenkins at boot time
Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/jenkins; bad; vendor preset: enabled)
Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Tue 2017-08-01 05:39:06 UTC; 7ms ago
Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)
Process: 3700 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/jenkins start (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Aug 01 05:39:06 ip-0 systemd[1]: Starting LSB: Start Jenkins ....
Aug 01 05:39:06 ip-0 jenkins[3700]: ERROR: No Java executable ...
Aug 01 05:39:06 ip-0 jenkins[3700]: If you actually have java ...
Aug 01 05:39:06 ip-0 systemd[1]: jenkins.service: Control pro...1
Aug 01 05:39:06 ip-0 systemd[1]: Failed to start LSB: Start J....
Aug 01 05:39:06 ip-0 systemd[1]: jenkins.service: Unit entere....
Aug 01 05:39:06 ip-0 systemd[1]: jenkins.service: Failed with....
```

To fix the issue manually install Java Runtime Environment:

JDK version 9:

```
sudo apt install openjdk-9-jre
```

JDK version 8:

```
sudo apt install openjdk-8-jre
```

Open Jenkins configuration file:

```
sudo vi /etc/init.d/jenkins
```

Finally, append path to the new java executable (line 16):

```
PATH=/bin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/usr/sbin:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/bin/
```

Comment: To further improve your answer Andrew. As of the writing of this comment, v9 will NOT work and jenkins will fail with a "Incorrect Java Version found" so to fix that you should chose version 8 as your default java environment by simply running `sudo update-alternatives --config java` and then chosing your version 8

Comment: In my case, changing from Java 9 to java 8 make it. Thanks to the comment from  @privilegue

Comment: @Andrew: I had the same issue on ubuntu 16.04 with java8. For me it worked to use the latest jenkins (LTS) version.

Comment: Didn't work with `jdk-13`. You have to stick to `jdk-8` in most cases. more details here [https://jenkins.io/doc/administration/requirements/java/](https://jenkins.io/doc/administration/requirements/java/)

Comment: `sudo apt install openjdk-11-jre` worked for me on Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS. install this before installing Jenkins.

Comment: @megachill great answer, solved to me.

Answer (score 22):

ERROR:  Linux / Centos:

> Job for jenkins.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status jenkins.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.

Solution:

- Edit the Jenkins init file by doing

  ```
  sudo vi /etc/init.d/jenkins
  ```
- Add your own Java path, for example:

  ```
  /opt/oracle/product/java/jdk1.8.0_45/bin/java
  ```
- Restart the service:

  ```
  sudo service jenkins start
  sudo service jenkins status
  sudo service jenkins stop
  ```

Comment: Where do we add the java path?

Comment: you should add the path in candidates=" "

Answer (score 14):

I had a similar problem on Ubuntu 16.04. Thanks to @Guna I figured out that I had to manually install Java (`sudo apt install openjdk-8-jre`).

Comment: I doubt that this works. The jenkins [documentation](https://jenkins.io/doc/administration/requirements/java/) explicitly says: 'Java 8 is the ONLY supported runtime environment, both 32-bit and 64-bit versions are supported'  and 'Java 9 is not supported'.
Please update your answer.

Comment: @smartmeta Thanks for noting this, I updated the answer. It was working for me back then, though (at least I did not notice any issues). Probably "not supported" only means they do not test/maintain with this version.

Answer (score 9):

I had a similar issue on CentOS 7 while a correct version of Java was installed and `java -version` gave a nice result.

Collecting multiple answers from different SO threads I did the following:

**Make sure Java is installed (and version is compatible with Jenkins)**
There're some tricks if saying about CentOS, this is mentioned in official Jenkins tutorial **[here](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Installing+Jenkins+on+Red+Hat+distributions#InstallingJenkinsonRedHatdistributions-ImportantNoteonCentOSJava)**

If Java is installed and available, when running `java -v` output should look like this:

```
    ~>$java -version
    openjdk version "1.8.0_161"
    OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_161-b14)
    OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.161-b14, mixed mode)
```

**Add a path to Java to your /etc/rc.d/init.d/jenkins**

```
   ~>$ sudo vim /etc/rc.d/init.d/jenkins
    candidates="
    /etc/alternatives/java
    /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0/bin/java
    /usr/lib/jvm/jre-1.8.0/bin/java
    /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0/bin/java
    /usr/lib/jvm/jre-1.7.0/bin/java
    /usr/bin/java
    /usr/java/jdk1.8.0_162/bin/java ##add your java path here
    "
```

**How to get your 'real' path to java distributive which is called when you type smth like `java -v`**
Follow **[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5251323/where-can-i-find-the-java-sdk-in-linux?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)** SO thread

If steps above didn't help, try to make sure all permission issues are resolved:

1. If Jenkins fails to run Java, it could be `jenkins` user doesn't have permissions to run it, then change `jenkins` to `root` in config (described **[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38352806/jenkins-not-able-to-access-java-localhost-jenkins807-starting-jenkins-bash?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)**)
2. Try to play with `chmod` setting `755` permissions to `java` installation folder

**And finally what helped me in result**
When I did run `journalctl -xe` as was suggested when I've tried to `sudo service jenkins start`, I got similar Java stacktrace:

```
Starting CloudBees Jenkins Enterprise Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
at Main._main(Main.java:140)
at Main.main(Main.java:98)
Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: /tmp/jna--1712433994/jna7387046629130767794.tmp: /tmp/jna--1712433994/jna7387046629130767794.tmp: failed to map segment from shared object: Operation not permitted
at java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load(Native Method)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary0(ClassLoader.java:1937)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1822)
at java.lang.Runtime.load0(Runtime.java:809)
at java.lang.System.load(System.java:1086)
at com.sun.jna.Native.loadNativeDispatchLibraryFromClasspath(Native.java:761)
at com.sun.jna.Native.loadNativeDispatchLibrary(Native.java:736)
at com.sun.jna.Native.<clinit>(Native.java:131)
at com.sun.akuma.CLibrary.<clinit>(CLibrary.java:89)
at com.sun.akuma.JavaVMArguments.resolvePID(JavaVMArguments.java:128)
at com.sun.akuma.JavaVMArguments.ofLinux(JavaVMArguments.java:116)
at com.sun.akuma.JavaVMArguments.of(JavaVMArguments.java:104)
at com.sun.akuma.JavaVMArguments.current(JavaVMArguments.java:92)
at com.sun.akuma.Daemon.daemonize(Daemon.java:106)
at com.sun.akuma.Daemon.all(Daemon.java:88)
... 6 more
```

The problem is that Jenkins tries to launch `JNA` library from `/tmp` dir which is marked as `noexec` by default, so we it could be fixed by creating a temporary directory in a `/jenkins` path so it could be executed.
The full way to do this is described **[here by CloudBees support](https://support.cloudbees.com/hc/en-us/articles/215281717-Jenkins-fails-to-start-with-JNA-error)** (thanks a lot for them)

I hope something from this list will help (as well I mostly leave it for me in the future when I'll have to install Jenkins for CentOs again :)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I met the same problem as you mentioned "failed to map segment from shared object"               The answer in the link helped.

Comment: I was getting a simlar error to you on RHEL 7 and followed option 1 from the cloudbees support page which fixed the issue for me as well. Hero.

Comment: Thanks @rodikno, centos7 and the problem was with /tmp permissions.

Answer (score 9):

Before you install Jenkins you should install JDK:

```
apt install openjdk-8-jre
```

After this install Jenkins:

```
apt-get install jenkins
```

And check Jenkins status (should be 'active'):

```
systemctl status jenkins.service
```

Answer (score 6):

The easiest possible fix for this issue if it is a AWS linux instance

```
sudo yum install java-1.8.0 -y 

sudo yum remove java-1.7.0-openjdk
```

Answer (score 4):

Still fighting the same error on both ubuntu, ubuntu derivatives and opensuse. This is a great way to bypass and move forward until you can fix the actual issue.

Just use the docker image for jenkins from dockerhub.

***docker pull jenkins/jenkins***

***docker run  -itd -p 8080:8080 --name jenkins_container  jenkins***

Use the browser to navigate to:

**localhost:8080** or **my_pc:8080**

To get at the token at the path given on the login screen:

***docker exec -it jenkins_container /bin/bash***

Then navigate to the token file and copy/paste the code into the login screen. You can use the edit/copy/paste menus in the kde/gnome/lxde/xfce terminals to copy the terminal text, then paste it with ctrl-v

**War File**

Or use the jenkins.war file. For development purposes you can run jenkins as your user (or as jenkins) from the command line or create a short script in /usr/local or /opt to start it.

Download the jenkins.war from the jenkins download page:

**https://jenkins.io/download/**

Then put it somewhere safe, ~/jenkins would be a good place.

***mkdir ~/jenkins; cp ~/Downloads/jenkins.war ~/jenkins***

Then run:

***nohup java -jar ~/jenkins/jenkins.war > ~/jenkins/jenkins.log 2>&1***

To get the initial admin password token, copy the text output of:

***cat /home/my_home_dir/.jenkins/secrets/initialAdminPassword***

and paste that into the box with ctrl-v as your initial admin password.

Hope this is detailed enough to get you on your way...

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue, and when I checked if Java is installed I realised it's not, so installing Java solved the problem for me.

Check for java:

```
java -version
```

If Java is installed in the system, the command will return the java version otherwise it will show a message like this.

```
The program 'java' can be found in the following packages:
 * default-jre
 * gcj-5-jre-headless
 * openjdk-8-jre-headless
 * gcj-4.8-jre-headless
 * gcj-4.9-jre-headless
 * openjdk-9-jre-headless
```

To install java use the following command.

```
sudo apt-get install default-jre
```

Answer (score 4):

[100 %]Solved. I had the same problem today. I checked my server space

```
df-h
```

I saw that server is out of space so i check which directory has most size by

```
sudo du -ch / | sort -h
```

I saw 12.2G    /var/lib/jenkins so i entered this folder and cleared all the logs by

```
cd /var/libs/jenkins
rm *
```

and restart the jenkins it will work normal

```
sudo systemctl restart jenkins.service
```

Answer (score 3):

Jenkins, by default, makes use of port 8080, please make sure its not occupied by other applications.
To check if a port is available, try running

```
curl localhost:8080
```

If port is available, this should result in an error like:

> curl: (7) Failed to connect to localhost port 8080: Connection refused

If the port is occupied, Jenkins port can be changed by:

```
sudo systemctl edit --full jenkins.service
```

and setting:

> ```
> Environment="JENKINS_PORT=<ANY_AVAILABLE_PORT>"
> ```

Then run:

```
   sudo systemctl restart jenkins.service
```

Answer (score 2):

I was trying to install it in kubuntu 18.04, and i was already sure that i had java installed,
I confirmed by trying

> java -version

I got the output like that

```
java version "1.8.0_91"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_91-b14)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.91-b14, mixed mode)
```

Since I already know that my java PATH variables are defined in /etc/environment file, I added that file to the top of /etc/init.d/jenkins file

```
source /etc/environment
```

you can even remove the PATH from /etc/init.d/jenkins file, since it's already defined in /etc/environment

after that, i restarted my jenkins server,and it seemed to start working fine from localhost:8080

Answer (score 2):

In my case, **the port 8080 was taken by some other service** (Apache Airflow).

So I edit the HTTP port in this file:

```
sudo vi /etc/default/jenkins
```

And then started the service and it worked:

```
sudo service jenkins start
```

I was on Ubuntu 18.04 and installed openjdk-8

Answer (score 1):

For ubuntu 16.04, there is firewall issue. You need to open 8080 port using following command:

```
sudo ufw allow 8080
```

Detailed steps are given here: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-jenkins-on-ubuntu-16-04

Comment: But the question is about centOS, not Ubuntu.

Answer (score 1):

Installing Java fixed this issue for me!

please try to install it like this:

```
sudo apt install openjdk-11-jdk
```

Answer (score 1):

For Amazon Linux:

```bash
sudo wget -O /etc/yum.repos.d/jenkins.repo https://pkg.jenkins.io/redhat/jenkins.repo

sudo rpm --import https://pkg.jenkins.io/redhat/jenkins.io.key

sudo amazon-linux-extras install epel

sudo amazon-linux-extras install java-openjdk11

sudo yum install jenkins

systemctl start jenkins
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This was helpfu but still didnt work, I was able to get it to work but my last 2 lines are the following:

`yum install -y jenkins` (added the -y flag) and 
`service jenkins start` (instead of systemctl)

Answer (score 1):

In my case, my first error where I got the error message above was due to /usr/share/jenkins/jenkins.war missing. I had manually set it as a symlink, and running apt-get upgrade removed the symlink.
Fix was to download the latest jenkins.war from jenkins.io (or restoring the symlink to point to the latest version).

After this I still got the same error, and by starting Jenkins manually:

`java -jar jenkins.war`

I got the following error message

```
SEVERE: Running with Java class version 52, which is older than the Minimum required version 55. See https://jenkins.io/redirect/java-support/
Jenkins requires Java versions [17, 11] but you are running with Java 1.8
```

Upgrading openjdk to version 11 (or 17) solved the problem:

```
apt-get install openjdk-11-jre
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding on to what has been already answered by Guna Sekaran. Jenkins need the user jenkins to be present in order to run the jenkins as a service.

To add the user, run `useradd jenkins` as root, and run `passwd jenkins` as root before starting Jenkins as a service.

Answer (score 0):

Open the jenkins service config file `sudo vim /etc/rc.d/init.d/jenkins`

set candidates as follows:

```bash
candidates="

/etc/alternatives/java

/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0/bin/java

/usr/lib/jvm/jre-1.8.0/bin/java

/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0/bin/java

/usr/lib/jvm/jre-1.7.0/bin/java

/usr/bin/java

**/usr/java/jdk1.8.0_162/bin/java**    ##add your java path

"
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to install Java.
It did work after installing Java version 8,
using this command :  sudo apt install openjdk-8-jre-headless

Answer (score 0):

Looks like java version conflicts.

Please refer https://medium.com/lucian-daniliuc/upgrading-jenkins-on-ubuntu-14-04-lts-df3e1209f98c

Answer (score 0):

I faced same issue while setting up jenkins, the problem is that java is not installed and hence not available in path.

The simplest way is to use scp here to copy jdk binaries to aws ec2 box, script won't work if you make one as they keep on updating download urls(Orale, i mean):
    scp -i C:/Users/key-pair.pem jdk-8u191-linux-x64.tar.gz ec2- 
    user@54.183.220.7:~/

```
$cd /opt

$sudo cp /home/ec2-user/jdk* .

$sudo chmod +x jdk*

$sudo tar xzf jdk-8u191-linux-x64.tar.gz

$sudo tar xzf jdk-8u191-linux-x64.tar.gz

$cd jdk1.8.0_191/

$sudo alternatives --install /usr/bin/java java /opt/jdk1.8.0_191/bin/java 2

$sudo alternatives --config java
```

Here I download tar.gz file in loal windows and transferred over scp to AWS ec2-user, default dir. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

I had below error:

> Job for jenkins.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status jenkins.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.

Solution was to revert the NAME to jenkins in the below file (Earlier I have changed it to 'NAME=ubuntu'):

```
sudo vi /etc/default/jenkins
    NAME=jenkins
```

Now restart passed:

```
sudo service jenkins restart
sudo systemctl restart jenkins.service
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the issue was of unsupported java version

Check the file `/etc/init.d/jenkins` to find out which java versions are supported.

To find which java versions are supported, run

```
grep -m 1 "JAVA_ALLOWED_VERSIONS" /etc/init.d/jenkins
```

The output will be like this(your's might be different)

```
JAVA_ALLOWED_VERSIONS=( "1.8" "11" )
```

In my case version 1.8 and 11 are supported. I will be going with version 11.

Install the supported version of jre using command

For ubuntu/debian

```
sudo apt install openjdk-11-jre
```

For centOS use

```
sudo yum install java-11-openjdk-devel
```

Find the path to newly installed jre

For ubuntu/debian path is

```
/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/bin/java
```

You can find the path on centOS under `/usr/lib/jvm/`

Modify the file `/etc/init.d/jenkins`
At line number 28, replace the `` JAVA=`type -p java` ``  with `JAVA='/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/bin/java'`

Now run command to reload the systemctl daemon

```
sudo systemctl daemon-reload
```

Start the jenkins service

```
sudo systemctl start jenkins
```

Answer (score 0):

[root~]# systemctl start jenkins

Job for jenkins.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status jenkins.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.

[root~]#
[root~]# systemctl status jenkins.service

```
● jenkins.service - LSB: Jenkins Automation Server
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/rc.d/init.d/jenkins; bad; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Thu 2021-08-26 03:31:13 UTC; 12s ago
     Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)
  Process: 3465 ExecStart=/etc/rc.d/init.d/jenkins start (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Aug 26 03:31:13 ip-172-31-11-0.ap-south-1.compute.internal systemd[1]: Starting LSB: Jenkins Automation Server...
Aug 26 03:31:13 ip-172-31-11-0.ap-south-1.compute.internal jenkins[3465]: Starting Jenkins File "/usr/bin/java" is not executable.
Aug 26 03:31:13 ip-172-31-11-0.ap-south-1.compute.internal jenkins[3465]: [FAILED]
Aug 26 03:31:13 ip-172-31-11-0.ap-south-1.compute.internal systemd[1]: jenkins.service: control process exited, code=exited status=1
Aug 26 03:31:13 ip-172-31-11-0.ap-south-1.compute.internal systemd[1]: Failed to start LSB: Jenkins Automation Server.
Aug 26 03:31:13 ip-172-31-11-0.ap-south-1.compute.internal systemd[1]: Unit jenkins.service entered failed state.
Aug 26 03:31:13 ip-172-31-11-0.ap-south-1.compute.internal systemd[1]: jenkins.service failed.
```

I had this problem. and the problem was that I haven't installed java. This is for Amazon Linux. To install Java on Amazon Linux use : sudo yum install java.

Answer (score 0):

same error in my case,I tried all the above solutions ,none of them work because java is not the problem here.Please follow this steps for success.

before hitting sudo yum install jenkins java-1.8.0-openjdk-devel -y, you need to proceed this below step

```
step1: sudo amazon-linux-extras install epel -y
step2:sudo vi vim /etc/yum.repos.d/epelfordaemonize.repo  (it will open  vim)
step3:Enter this command after step2(vim is open)

   [daemonize]
   baseurl=https://download-ib01.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/7/x86_64/
   gpgcheck=no
   enabled=yes
step4: For saving those command, type :wq and hit enter again write :wq and hit enter,it will save and return back.
step5: Now,sudo yum install jenkins java-1.8.0-openjdk-devel -y,it will work
```

Answer (score 0):

Install the certificates-

- sudo apt install ca-certificates

then,
Try Updating & Upgrading the packages-

- sudo apt upgrade
- sudo apt update

Then follow the link to install the Jenkins :)

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-jenkins-on-ubuntu-18-04

Answer (score 0):

I use docker for jenkins.
You should be use `https://hub.docker.com/r/jenkins/jenkins` instead `https://hub.docker.com/_/jenkins`

Answer (score 0):

First, install JDK version 8:

```
sudo apt install openjdk-8-jre
```

Second, Choose version 8 as your default java environment by simply running

```
sudo update-alternatives --config java
```

Finally, Run

```
sudo systemctl start jenkins
```

Now, open port `8080` to login to Jenkins!

To stop it run:

```
sudo systemctl stop jenkins
```

Answer (score -1):

```
vi /etc/init.d/jenkins
```

add:

```
/usr/lib/jvm/java/jre/bin/java
```

Comment: Thanks for your input. But maybe it is a good idea to read the [Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to learn how to ask and answer questions

Answer (score -1):

In my case I were starting jenkins service from root instead of jenkins user

i did

```
sed -i 's/JENKINS_USER="jenkins"/JENKINS_USER="root"/g  /etc/sysconfig/jenkins
```

then

```
service jenkins restart
```

all work well

Answer (score -3):

Do nothing ,if you want install Jenkins you should only follow official page of Jenkins ..okey only ..it will solve all your problem because above all answers was given according to old version of Jenkins

Comment: this is equivalent to telling someone who's having trouble with their car to do nothing and follow the factory's instruction manual, and you won't have issues.

Comment: @ZachFolwick I think it is more like "Swap your car for a newer one, which is free and does not have these problems."

Answer (score -4):

rm -rf /var/log/jenkins
too big the log

Comment: I don't think so. He have just install a new jenkins service.